# Server-grade SDK that can load a PDF file and execute the calculation and validation code snippets?

Tags: c#, javascript, pdf

Popular PDF toolkits, such as iTextSharp and Datalogics are great at loading and parsing PDF files. However, they are not able to execute calculations and validations embedded in a form-enabled PDF. Those code snippets are simply exposed as field-level string properties.

Is there a server-grade (not Adobe Reader plugin) toolkit or SDK that can load a PDF file and execute the calculation and validation code snippets?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any toolkit but between these two documentation sources you might be able to throw together a basic expression processor that will handle your calculation and validation needs.  Might be a great open source addition to iTextSharp!

Looks like [this documentation](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xml/formcalc_2.0.pdf) might be just what you need to get started writing that converter from FormCalc to [C# Expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)!

"You can have the C# or Visual Basic compiler create an expression tree for you based on an anonymous lambda expression, or you can create expression trees manually by using the System.Linq.Expressions namespace."

Comment: I was actually looking at Jint (http://jint.codeplex.com/) as a Javascript execution engine. Unfortunately I haven't been able to set it up so it will deal with expressions like MyFormField.rawValue correctly (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905409).

Comment: I sure wish I had more time to dabble in this, it sounds like a really interesting problem to solve!  It sounds like you are going in the right direction though.  You might look at something more mainstream like Rhino  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_(JavaScript_engine) for JS execution as it has a TON of users.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Datalogics by name, we do (yes, I work for Datalogics) offer a [Java based PDF Toolkit](http://www.datalogics.com/products/pdf/pdfjavatoolkit/) that handles the javascript in PDF forms correctly.

You can also test it out by using the [FillForm](http://dev.datalogics.com/pdf-webapi/fillform/) service in our PDF WebAPI.